# There's an nginx process listening on port 80 and I don't know how it got there

Tags: apache, nginx

I use a digital ocean droplet as my development environment. The droplet is DO's LAMP stack droplet on Ubuntu 14.04. I've got apache running to access my mysql database with phpmyadmin.

Recently phpmyadmin stopped working inexplicably. I checked it out and it looked like apache wasn't starting properly. I get the following error:

```
 * Restarting web server apache2
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.0.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
(98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
(98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
AH00015: Unable to open logs
Action 'start' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.\
```

So it looks like port 80 is being taken up by another process. Someone suggested to me that I use `netstat` to figure out which process it is. Sure enough `sudo netstat -tapen | grep ":80"` revealed that there were some other processes listening on port 80:

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          8849        920/nginx
tcp        0      0 104.131.29.69:8000      0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1000       10361       1683/php5       
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      0          8850        920/nginx
```

So I tried to kill the process as per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14168351/cant-listen-on-port-80-with-my-server?answertab=votes#tab-top) answer. When I did, running `netstat` again yielded this

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          8849        921/nginx: worker p
tcp        0      0 104.131.29.69:8000      0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1000       10361       1683/php5       
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      0          8850        921/nginx: worker p
```

So the process seems to have just changed numbers but didn't die.

I also tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10160339/starting-apache-fails-could-not-bind-to-address-0-0-0-080?answertab=votes#tab-top) answer but nothing changed.

I have no idea what this nginx process is--I don't remember having ever started an nginx process on my server and in case I don't know how it could have survived my restarting the server various times (which I also tried). Several people suggested using netstat to find out what's listening on the port but I'm not sure what to do now that I've found it. Also why is it surviving my restarting the server? I'm pretty sure apache, or the php server that you see up there would both have to be restarted when the server's turned off.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you get when you type `service nginx status`? If it says running, try `sudo service nginx stop` instead of killing the proc. If nginx was installed through the package manager the logs in `/var/log/apt/` might provide more info as to when, etc...

Comment: `service nginx status` does return that it's running. After running `sudo service nginx stop` and checking the status again it reports that it's not running. If I restart the server though and check the status again it once again reports that it's running.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This command will show you which process is using port 80:

```
sudo lsof -i:80
```

Make sure to use "sudo".

Answer (score 1):

Probably an init service, which will restart on system boot.

Comment: That seems likely--I tried farmck's suggestion showed the PIDs and I was able to kill them all and get apache restarted properly, but if I restart the server they come back again.

The question is how do I avoid the service starting each time?

Comment: lsof should give you the process name. If not,  use this command to see the process name:   ps afx | grep [the_pid]

Answer (score 0):

Stop nginx using following command.

```
sudo /etc/init.d/nginx stop
```